# clang tidy bug when fix readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

when i use clang-tidy to add braces in short statement there is a bug.
The code

```
else
    _pContext(blabla);
```

is replaced by

```
else
{_}
pContext(blabla);
```

do you know how to fixe it ?
my .clang-tidy fil is like that

```
Checks:          'readability-braces-around-statements,readability-identifier-naming,modernize-use-override'
HeaderFilterRegex: ''
AnalyzeTemporaryDtors: true
CheckOptions:
  - key:             readability-braces-around-statements.ShortStatementLines
    value:           '0'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberPrefix
    value:           '_'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMemberPrefix
    value:           '_'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.MemberSuffix
    value:           '_'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ProtectedMemberPrefix
    value:           '_'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.PublicMemberPrefix
    value:           '_'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassMemberCase
    value:           'camelBack'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.PublicMemberCase
    value:           'camelBack'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ProtectedMemberCase
    value:           'camelBack'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.PrivateMemberCase
    value:           'camelBack'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantCase
    value:           'UPPER_CASE'
  - key:             readability-identifier-naming.ClassConstantPrefix
    value:           ''
  - key:             modernize-use-override
    value:           'OverrideSpelling'
```